# clicking HTML textarea on Android brings up the keyboard but then hides right after

Tags: android, html, angularjs, android-softkeyboard, chromium

It's an Android hybrid app.

Within WebView, the loaded HTML has this code.

```
<span ng-controller="FormController">
    <textarea ng-model="note"></textarea>

    <input type="button" class="notes-btn" ng-click="saveNote()" value="save notes">

    <input type="button" class="notes-btn" ng-click="getAll()" value="email notes">

    <input type="button" class="notes-btn" ng-click="clearNote()" value="clear this note">

    <input type="button" class="notes-btn" ng-click="clearAll()" value="clear all notes">
</span>
```

Clicking the textarea will bring up the keyboard, I can see it animating up but then it animates down right away, on Tablet it doesn't appear at all, wondering what's causing the issue?

Please advise.

**Edit**

For some reason I do see the selection arrow (blue color) as soon as I tap on the textarea for a brief moment and then keyboard hides itself.

I don't have any javascript attached to textarea other than what angular does.

**Edit 2**

I've added some console statements

```
<textarea onclick="console.log('click')" onfocus="console.log('focus')" onblur="console.log('lost focus')"></textarea>
```

and i could see focus, click and lose focus in the console as soon as i tap on the textarea, something is triggering lost in focus as soon as I click in the textarea.